# Why when I extend a list does it have 'NoneType' as type?

Tags: python, list, extend

I am looking to extend a list and have the following

```
ListA = list(x)
ListB = list(y)
ListC = ListA.extend(ListB)
```

This gives `ListC` as having `<type 'NoneType'>` and I am wondering why this isn't just a list as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Because `extend(..)` works **inplace**. It does **not return something**. You can also use `listA + listB` to create a combined list.

Comment: well, it returns `None`, which is something, right? ;) I think the most important point here is that (generally) methods on python types either modify the state of the instance **or** return a not-`None` something (not both). `extend` modifies the state (by extending the list `ListA`) and therefore returns `None`.

Comment: @MSeifert `list.pop` and `dict.setdefault` for example can both modify the state and return something.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I think of them (there is also a `dict.pop` and `dict.popitem)` as "special cases" and to quote the Zen: `Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules. Although practicality beats purity.` Maybe these were considered "practical"? :)

Comment: @MSeifert I think your statement didn't say "generally" at first (or maybe I just missed it), so to me it sounded like it's always the case. Anyway, I think it's good to see an exception example. I prefer the `setdefault` example over `popitem` because it shows that it's not just "destructive" methods that do this.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yes, I modified the text before I saw your comment, so it could very well be that it wasn't there before. And I'm glad you gave the example!

Comment: @MSeifert Btw, I don't think that "rule" is valid. For constructive methods maybe, but not for destructive. For destructive ones I think it's very appropriate that the destructed data is returned. Pisses me off every time I have to use both `top` and `pop` on a C++ stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`extend`, like many other list operations, operates in-place and returns None. `ListA` is modified with the extra elements.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define ListC as a list type.

As you know, list() is a function; which generates a list type.

list.extend does not. Instead, it modifies the given list.

Look at your code again.

```
ListA = list(x) ## You defined ListA as a list type; with list(x). 

ListB = list(y) ## You defined ListB as a list type; with list(y). 

ListC = ListA.extend(ListB) ## ListC is not defined as a list type.
```

Therefore, ListC returns NoneType.

It is good that you noticed the difference between + and list.extend(). Keep it up and good luck.

Comment: I'm not sure that your explanation is clear enough. `ListC` is defined, and it's assigned to a result of `ListA.extend(ListB)`. Result of extend is always `None` because it changes mutable object "inplace". Everything depends on actual call: `list.extend` changes existing object, `ListA+ListB` returns a new list

Comment: You are correct. I meant ListC is not defined 'as a list type'. I just edited. Thanks.